# Mohr's circle: maximum normal stress tensor

Tags: stresses

Given:

$$ 
   \sigma_{ij}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   -20 & 60 \\
   60 & 90 \\
  \end{array} } \right],\quad i,j=x,y
$$

I want to find the principle stress tensor $\sigma_{ij}^{pr}$.
Using the [Mohr's Cirlce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%27s_circle), I get:

$$\sigma_{max}=116.39,\sigma_{min}=-46.39$$

the points where the circle intersects with the $x(\sigma_{xx},\sigma_{yy})$ axis.

From there, how do these points make up the principle stress tensor?

Is

$$ 
   \sigma_{ij}^{pr}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   116.39 & 0 \\
   0 & -46.39 \\
  \end{array} } \right],\quad i,j=x,y
$$
correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you determined for $\sigma_{\mathit{max}}$ and $\sigma_\mathit{min}$ are correct. However, your answer is only partially correct.

The value of $\sigma^\mathrm{pr}$ has to be expressed in the principal coordinate system. You can calculate the angle of the principal system to your original coordinate system using:
$$
tan(2\varphi) = \frac{2\tau_{xy}}{\sigma_x-\sigma_y} = \frac{2 * 60}{-20-90}
$$
$$
\varphi_1 \approx 23.74°
$$

So yes the values are correct, but your coordinate system $x^\mathrm{pr}, y^\mathrm{pr}$ is rotated by $\varphi_1$ degrees, compared to your original coordinate system $x, y$.

Comment: So, the final answer is the matrix $\sigma_{ij}^{pr}$ I found plus the angle of rotation $\varphi_1$ ?

Comment: Yes, and call the axes something different. For example $x^\mathrm{pr}, y^\mathrm{pr}$.